# Redirect modified output of a program back to its input

Tags: bash, grep, irc, redirectstandardoutput

For fun, I want to type something in Bash that will connect to an IRC server and automatically respond to PING messages

For example, I have the following output from `telnet`

```
Connected to irc.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
PING :12341234
```

If I pipe this to grep and then sed, I can easily turn this output into `PONG :12341234`, but how do I send it back to the standard input stream of telnet?

Additionally, I'd like to still being to manually send input using the keyboard

Comment: There's an IRC client written entirely in `sed` and shell script, though the original location at `sno.pp.se` is no longer available. It's somewhat more complex than your first sketch, though still remarkably compact. Search for `shirc`.

Comment: Some further googling reveals that it has probably dropped off the net for good. I have a fork somewhere although I'm not sure if I can locate it in my backups. Ping me here in a week or two if I don't come back with a link.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is known as an "echo server". It is fairly easy to do with `netcat` and it's variants (`nc` or `netcat`, `ncat`, etc.).

For example:

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --exec "/bin/cat"
```

In another shell

```
telnet localhost 2000
```

Whatever you send will be replied by ncat.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is more like an "echo client" than an echo server.